# efficient is_in(vector<string>& S, string P) function

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a set of S string { S0, S2, S3,..., Sn-1 }, and a string P, how to determine the function **bool is_in( string, vector )** without doing the obvious loop.

Meaning that I don't want to do this:

```
 bool is_in(vector<string>& S, string P)
 {
      for(int i=0; i<S.size(); i++) 
            if(P == S[i]) return true;
      return false; 
 }
```

Ideally, I would like to have a sort of hash function, that I could compute *a priori*. Something like this:

```
 bool is_in(vector<string>& S, string P)
 {
       someHashType h = hash( S );
       if( someFunction( h, S ) return true;
       return false;
 }
```

**Note:**

- S is s static vector (in my case, size 1000, unsorted)
- P an entry of a collection of strings I'm testing against S (also unsorted) (in my case, 10M) -
- So that's why I need to be fast.
- This is NOT a homework problem - But part of a large scale software.

Comment: `const auto hash = [](const std::string& s) -> char { return s[0]; };` ?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve inside of someFunction that'd make it better than a plain for loop?

Comment: Is this homework question?

Comment: What about `std::set`/`std::unordered_set`?

Comment: Is this a random vector that changes often, or could you sort it first and do a binary search? And how many strings are there?

Comment: S is s static vector - in my case, size 1000. P is a collection of strings I'm testing against S (in my case, 10M) - so that's why I need to be fast.

Comment: Why not use set: well, I want to avoid string comparisons,

Comment: Use `unordered_set` then, which has O(1) lookup in the average case (with one hash plus one string comparison at each lookup). Still, even `set` isn't going to be that bad, it's O(log N) lookup (its main problem is bad locality and heavy heap usage, not number of comparisons).

Comment: Unordered set minimizes string comparisons. You cannot avoid them entirely.

Comment: *Trie* is another good data structure for sets of strings.

Comment: If your strings in the vector do not change, you might try [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). I am aware of the [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) variant, never tried it myself, though. If it does not match your needs, there are others, too...

Comment: Tries are another interesting data structure, but in my experience they usually shine when you are interested in prefixes or suffixes more than exact matches. Hash tables generally are better in this last case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what I was looking for:

There is a tool called [BloomFilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) which allows a pre-computed hash of a collection of strings.

I developed my solution around the code located at [C++Bloom Filter Library](http://www.partow.net/programming/bloomfilter/index.html)

The code would go like this:

- insert all strings to the 'bloom' filter
- check if a given string is in the filter.

The advantage is that the strings don't need to be storage in memory, as it would be in a set, unordered_set or any object like that.

in my particular object, I had a table of strings with 10M strings (800MB).
The size of the filter in memory is around 20M, and the search is quite faster.

The 'Bloom Filter' is an statistical algorithm, so it can have a few false positives. - But the probability for that is quite low (controlled by a parameter)

Note that there is no false negative.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "I want this function to be faster" is that it does, nearly always, involve SOME extra work somewhere else. And that may or may not mean that the improvement is "worth it". All that depends on what your collection of strings that you are looking for is used for in the rest of the code. If it's just a "is the word in this list then do X" (e.g. a bad word check for commit messages, must not have swear-words and company names in them), then I would change the vector to an `unordered_set`. That has a O(1) search time, and would look something like:

```
 bool is_in(unordered_set<string>& S, string P)
 {
       auto it = S.find(P);
       return (it != S.end());
 }
```

But this will of course have consequences elsewhere, and if you rely on the list being a vector so that for example iterating over it is fast somewhere else in the code, this will probably slow that part down.

Edit: You have, I take it, profiled your code in a real use-case and found this particular function to take a significant amount of time. Otherwise, you'd be better off measuring that FIRST.